# RTC Memory ESP8266 12-E read an write

Tags: esp8266

What would be the right syntax for writing a variable lets say the int 100 into the RTC Memory of an ESP8266 12-E module and retrieve it after reboot or deep sleep.
I am using the Esp8622 12 E with an USB to serial converter and I am flashing it with arduino ide.

Comment: We need more information, you haven't told us what firmware you're using! However, if you're using NodeMCU, it's as simple as `rtcmem.write32()`.

Comment: I edited my question. I am not sure which firmware I an using since I always flash the module via arduino ide if that makes sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using the Arduino ESP8266 firmware, from your edit. Start by reading [the documentation](https://arduino-esp8266.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)...

I've not used the Arduino ESP8266 firmware, but it appears you can use `ESP.rtcUserMemoryWrite(offset, &data, sizeof(data))` and `ESP.rtcUserMemoryRead(offset, &data, sizeof(data))`.

For example,

```
...
int32_t foo = 100;
ESP.rtcUserMemoryWrite(0, &foo, sizeof(foo));
ESP.deepSleep(5e6);
...
```

and then

```
...
int32_t bar = 0;
ESP.rtcUserMemoryRead(0, &bar, sizeof(bar)));
// check the data
...
```

You will likely need to keep a checksum of your data and verify it after reading, in order to make sure that you have valid data.

This should persist across sleep, but I'm not sure if it persists across resets, and I'm pretty sure it doesn't persist across power cycles.

Comment: I'm getting an error: `invalid conversion from 'int32_t* {aka int*}' to 'uint32_t* {aka unsigned int*}' [-fpermissive]
 ESP.rtcUserMemoryWrite(0, &foo, sizeof(foo))` i tried `uint32_t bar = 0` and it compiled but it did not read back the right int, instead of 100 I got '2975063029'

Comment: Oh whoops, yeah I guess it wants a `uin32_t`. Replace in both places. If you're getting the wrong value, it may not be working properly. Also, check the return value of rtcUserMemoryRead()